# Android Project using Cordova 3.5 caches data in memory

Tags: android, cordova, caching, cordova-3.5

I have recently built a hybrid Android Project using Jquery Mobile, Andorid SDK 22.3 and Cordova 3.5 plugin. The application was build successfully. But while testing we observed that application is caching data in its memory.

E.g. when we login into the App using user credentials, the apps store the credentials. And in next attempt, it takes previously used credentials to login.

The issue gets resolved if we explicitly clear the cache memory of App. But again after next login, it stores the cache data.

Can anyone please suggest how to clear the cache memory programmatically?

Thanks and Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem by adding the following meta tag on your header tag.

```
<META HTTP-EQUIV="CACHE-CONTROL" CONTENT="NO-CACHE">
```